# Forcing browser to clear all cache and

Tags: javascript, caching, progressive-web-apps, service-worker

I am working on a Progressive Web App. It's using WorkBox. When a user visits this site for the first time, it loads and saves everything in the cache. It loads `sw.js` on first hit, where all the caching programming is done. The problem is that when I change the `sw.js`, the browser doesn't load the new version. Browser isn't even fetching `sw.js` in all subsequent reloads. The browser is only hitting loading `sw.js` from the network only once and only the first time. Never after this. Whenever I close all tabs and re-open the site, everything is being loaded from the cache. There is no way for me to tell the browser to forget all cache and update the Service Working logic.

When I investigated the headers, here are the response headers returned by the server when `sw.js` was loaded the first time.

```
GENERAL 

Request URL: https://example.com/sw.js
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 200 
Remote Address: 35.232.25.120:443
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin

RESPONSE HEADERS

accept-ranges: bytes
content-disposition: inline; filename="sw.js"
content-encoding: gzip
content-type: application/javascript; charset=utf-8
date: Wed, 29 Dec 2021 10:43:11 GMT
etag: "c9fad0c2f5560c6ca6392666ce60c766ac2e745a"
server: nginx/1.19.0
strict-transport-security: max-age=15724800; includeSubDomains
vary: Accept-Encoding

REQUEST HEADERS

:authority: example.com
:method: GET
:path: /sw.js
:scheme: https
accept: */*
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9
cache-control: max-age=0
cookie: _ga=GA1.3.1482851364.1640774590; _gid=GA1.3.498772445.1640774590; _gat_gtag_UA_175037391_1=1; amp_911ebe=adddib0vAFNA4kAE2aWvzU...1fo2sioje.1fo2siojf.0.1.1
referer: https://example.com/
sec-fetch-dest: serviceworker
sec-fetch-mode: same-origin
sec-fetch-site: same-origin
service-worker: script
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/95.0.4638.69 Safari/537.36
```

And following are the headers for `workbox-sw.js`

```
GENERAL
Request URL: https://storage.googleapis.com/workbox-cdn/releases/3.5.0/workbox-sw.js
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 200 
Remote Address: 142.250.180.48:443
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin

RESPONSE HEADERS

accept-ranges: bytes
access-control-allow-origin: *
age: 799
alt-svc: h3=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-29=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q050=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=":443"; ma=2592000,quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="46,43"
cache-control: public, max-age=31536000
content-encoding: gzip
content-length: 810
content-type: application/javascript; charset=utf-8
date: Wed, 29 Dec 2021 10:29:53 GMT
etag: "e9e8605ff1fa99d1d728c7bef35972e3"
expires: Thu, 29 Dec 2022 10:29:53 GMT
last-modified: Tue, 11 Sep 2018 14:57:59 GMT
server: UploadServer
vary: Accept-Encoding
x-goog-generation: 1536677879504420
x-goog-hash: crc32c=nfxN3w==
x-goog-hash: md5=6ehgX/H6mdHXKMe+81ly4w==
x-goog-metageneration: 1
x-goog-storage-class: MULTI_REGIONAL
x-goog-stored-content-encoding: gzip
x-goog-stored-content-length: 810
x-guploader-uploadid: ADPycdvVr9aa6mv9ryWENRCDQR0hmSBZZ3n3w0B5vnIKThJ-EFzRZaCLeyxxSaJhOZpMsSVEtWT1dtLnaxQwvUjKn2U

REQUEST HEADERS

:authority: storage.googleapis.com
:method: GET
:path: /workbox-cdn/releases/3.5.0/workbox-sw.js
:scheme: https
accept: */*
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9
cache-control: max-age=0
referer: https://example.com/
sec-fetch-dest: script
sec-fetch-mode: no-cors
sec-fetch-site: cross-site
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/95.0.4638.69 Safari/537.36
```

It clearly shows that these files have to be cached by the browser for 30 days...

Does it mean I have to wait for 30 days for `sw.js` to update itself?

How can I solve it?

Comment: A hard reload in the browser should force a reload of all resources and temporarily fix the problem. More generally, you should not be caching static files like this. Follow the best practices described [here](https://jakearchibald.com/2016/caching-best-practices/).

Comment: Thanks, but that's what I can do. I can't tell every user of the site to do this... So any way I can just do it from the server-side? like sending some headers?

Comment: Make sure not to cache the sw.js file in cache.

Comment: There are no headers you can send because there will be no request or response for a cached file. What you *can* do is stop referencing "sw.js" from your main code. Use a different name (or, better yet, follow the advice in the link and automatically generate a new name based on the contents of the file).